# docker-compose caused: are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log

phpfpm:
    build: ./mGSV
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html

mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
          - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
    ports:
          - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
          - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d 

phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8183:80
  environment:
    PMA_USER: root
    PMA_PASSWORD: admin
    PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

And my `mGSV/Dockerfile` is based on a php:5-fpm container and looks like this.

```
FROM php:5-fpm
...
```

During `docker-compose up --build` unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
Creating mgsvdocker2_nginx_1 ... error

ERROR: for mgsvdocker2_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/mictadlo/projects/mGSV-docker2/nginx/default\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ffca193aad22856bb6c8e1262fc6c001fde8c5354009a366eeb6d9092d50b63/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ffca193aad22856bb6c8e1262fc6c001fde8c5354009a366eeb6d9092d50b63/merged/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""Creating mgsvdocker2_phpmyadmin_1 ... done

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/mictadlo/projects/mGSV-docker2/nginx/default\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ffca193aad22856bb6c8e1262fc6c001fde8c5354009a366eeb6d9092d50b63/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ffca193aad22856bb6c8e1262fc6c001fde8c5354009a366eeb6d9092d50b63/merged/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

How is possible to check path are wrong set and any suggestions how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error while using docker on windows. ran the terminal as administrator and then ran a $docker volume prune

Have you tried using the path /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled?